Notepad++: Search and replace/delete timestamps in brackets []
I have a transcript that starts each line with a timestamp followed by 2 spaces and text, like this:
[00:00:00] Line 1
[00:00:02] Line 2

How can I search and replace(delete) all those timestamps and one of the spaces? Would be great if the line break would also be deleted, but not necessary.

What is the expected result?

What linebreak do you want to delete?

A quick & dirty regex is \[\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\]  , if that's the question.


Ctrl+H
Find what: ^\[.+?] (.+)\R?
Replace with: $1
TICK Wrap around
SELECT Regular expression
UNTICK . matches newline
Replace all


Thanks, that worked quite well. Could I (you) extend this to remove the line break? So the result would be "Line 1 Line 2" in one line?

@Poldi: See my edit. If it works for you, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, How to accept an answer

Follow These Steps

Ctrl+H \
Find what: [\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}] \
Replace with: $1 \
TICK Wrap-around \
SELECT Regular expression \
UNTICK. matches newline 7 Replace all


You might want to put a \ before the opening [ for it to work properly. (And what's with the huge font?)

Why did you (wrong) copy my answer?
